# Why electrons are freely moving in valence band? If they are moving why not any current?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Why electrons are freely moving in valence band? If they are moving why it does not have any current?
For all the cases?

Comment: In a metal? Semiconductor? Under what circumstances?

Answer (score 4):

> Why electrons are freely moving in valence band?

Electrons are moving in valence band due to thermal energy. You can refer to [kT energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KT_(energy))  for more information .

> if they are moving why it does not have any current? For all the cases?

Electrons are moving in random directions and the average movement of all electrons is 0. Current is only produced when they move in particular direction usually under the action of an electric field.

Comment: Will there motion seek any changes if we place them in magnetic field?

Answer (score 1):

To add one thing to Bhavay's answer: Full bands never carry current. If a band is full, then for every electron with wavevector $\vec{k}$, there is another with wavevector $-\vec{k}$, and the net current is zero.